# How can I check for exact length using jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate forms, how would you confirm that a string is exactly X characters long?

Comment: Note: this question and my answer are old. Take a look at some of the newer answers; they imply that better solutions are now possible.

Answer (score 58):

Since there is (currently) no built-in method for this, you'd need to add your own method. This would work:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
}, $.validator.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters."));
```

Which could then be used like this:

```
$("#formtovalidate").validate({
  rules: {
    somefield: {
      exactlength: 10
    }
   });
```

### Update - How it Works

I've been asked how this works. I don't know all the details; I modeled this method on previously existing ones. However, this is my best attempt to explain it.

- The function takes in `value`, `element`, and `param`.

  - `value` is the value entered in the field being validated
  - `element` is the field itself
  - `param` is whatever comes after the rule type and colon. In the example above, it's the 10 in `exactlength: 10`
- The next line is a `return` statement. This will give the final verdict of the validation method back to the code that called it. Any validation method that returns `true` is saying 'this field passes validation!' It will return the value of the line it's on.
- The `return` is followed by two declarations, separated by an 'or' operator (`||`).

  - The `||` operator means 'evaluate the item left of this. If it's true, return true. If not, try the one on the right. If it's true, return true. Otherwise, return false.'

    - The item on the left is `this.optional(element)`. If the element is not required in your rules, this will return true, and so will the validation. Which means 'If I don't tell you that this field is required, I don't care whether it validates.'
    - If the field is required, we move to the right side of the `||`. This is the actual validation test. It compares the length of the field's input with the length you specified it should be. If they are the same, it returns true, the method returns true, and validation passes. Otherwise, validation fails.

That's about it. For further help, see the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Plugin_methods), particularly the part about [custom validation methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

Comment: Probably wise to mark this one as answered? (even if you did answer it yourself  :P)

Comment: How does it work? Like what is element and param? I am not sure what this.optional(element) does either?

Thanks by the way it is what I needed.

Comment: where to define jQuery.validator.addMethod( ? it giving me error.

Comment: jQuery.format is deprecated. You have to use jQuery.validator.format instead

Answer (score 24):

example:

```
rules : {
"someFieldName":{digits:true,minlength:20,maxlength:20}
}
```

Comment: Ha! That's much simpler. The only downside is that the error messages may be a bit less clear than "please enter EXACTLY X characters." But it sure is easier to do. :) +1

Comment: @NathanLong you can override the error messages too. Check out my answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815512/246743

Answer (score 3):

You could also make the existing `rangelength` method support exact range by supplying a dynamic message like this:

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    rangelength: function(args, inputElement) {
        var isExactRange, min, max;

        // Cast arguments as numbers
        min = Number(args[0]);
        max = Number(args[1]);

        isExactRange = min === max;

        if (isExactRange) {
            return 'Please enter exactly ' + min + ' characters.';
        }


        return 'Please enter between ' + min + ' and ' + max + ' characters.';
    }
);
```

As can be seen, you can generate messages on the fly based on the arguments passed to the validation methods. Message callbacks are passed the validation method arguments as their first argument, and the input element being validated as their second argument.

This makes it possible to return one message when a exact range is specified, but another if upper and lower bounds are not the same.

To fallback to the default `rangelength` message, replace

```
'Please enter between ' + min + ' and ' + max + ' characters.'
```

with

```
$.validator.messages.rangelength
```

It would be nice if the official documentation would be updated, as it is difficult to navigate in and does not describe all functionalities of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the existing validation methods via data attributes, then just set your own validation message for clarity.

```
<input data-rule-minlength="8" data-rule-maxlength="8" data-msg-minlength="Exactly 8 characters please" data-msg-maxlength="Exactly 8 characters please">
```

Comment: I haven't tried your way, but it looks a lot simpler. This question is from '09. I added a comment above for people to try newer answers. Thanks for posting an updated approach.