# How to validate input number with exactly 12 numbers?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm sorry, this seems something easy to fix. I have been searching for a solution, but I can't find one that works.

So, I have an input for phone numbers,

```
<input class="only_number" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="">
```

but the problem is that the input is validating with 4 numbers or more and I need it to only accept 12 numbers. No more, no less.

What is the solution here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for submit button try like this

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if (!/^\d{12}$/.test($("#phone").val())) {
            alert("12 numbers are required");
            $("#phone").val('');
             event.preventDefault();
        }
 return;

});
```

---

make use of regular expression with focusout for validation

```
$( "#phone" )
  .focusout(function() {
    if (!/^\d{12}$/.test($("#phone").val())) {
        alert("12 numbers are required");
        $("#phone").val('');
    }
  });
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pcq3vrq/)

---

Code snippet:

```js
$("#phone")
  .focusout(function() {
    if (!/^\d{12}$/.test($("#phone").val())) {
      alert("12 numbers are required");
      $("#phone").val('');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="only_number" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, please? :)

Comment: @Timmy - please do accept - upvote answer it works for you

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I have a submit button and your code is not working unfortunatelly when I submit the phone number. :(

Comment: @Timmy - provided code for submit button also.....main validation part working in jsfiddler for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();(select your field here.)
intRegex = /^[0-9 ]+$/;
if((phone.length <> 12) || (!intRegex.test(phone)))
{
  alert('Please enter a valid phone number.');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is (currently) no built-in method for this, you'd need to add your own method. This would work:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
}, $.validator.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters."));
Which could then be used like this:

$("#formtovalidate").validate({
  rules: {
    somefield: {
      exactlength: 12
    }
   });
```

answer taken from [How can I check for exact length using jQuery Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229141/how-can-i-check-for-exact-length-using-jquery-validation)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <input pattern=".{12,12}">
      <input type="submit" value="I only accept 12 chars"></input>
</form>
```